# The rate of change of angle of attack

Tags: matlab, simulink

in the Aerospace Blockset in Simulink, the example model:

```
asbSkyHogg
```

in this block (asbSkyHogg/Vehicle System Model/Vehicle/3DOF to 6DOF/3DOF to 6DOF/calc alpha_dot) which is used to calcualate the rate of change of of angle of attack

[image]

The rate of change of of angle of attack is calculated based on the equation:

[image]

So, the acceleration  (input #3) in body axes should be transformed to wind axes using the DCM Body-to-Wind as shown in the picture... but why the transpose block is added here???!! In this case, it's actually transformed to body axes again!!

I tried to comment through the transpose block, but I need confirmation if I'm wrong or not, and why it's added.

Comment: The transpose block cannot undo what the body-to-wind block does. It’s there just to present the signal in the correct shape for the next calculation (matrix multiply).

Comment: @picchiolu, I'm sorry I didn't catch what you mean very well. 
I think the transpose reverses the DCM transformation matrix. So, DCM_Transposed x Ab actually is a transformation from wind to body frame. But Ab is already in body frame! so why?!

Comment: The only reasonable explanation, excluding such a blatant error on Mathworks' side, is that DCMwb is actually a wind-to-body transformation matrix, therefore its transpose becomes the body-to-wind transformation, which allows Ab to become Aw.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a mistake in the MATLAB.  The "Direction Cosine Matrix Body to Wind" output is a DCM that will express a Body-frame vector in the Wind-Frame (Vector transformation).  This block output matches this definition, and it is used this way when transforming Vb to Vw in the "3DOF to 6DOF" block.

As it is currently portrayed in asbSkyHogg, the wrong DCM is being applied to the Body-Frame Acceleration if the wind-frame acceleration is desired.